# Three.js how check collision with shader heightmap

Tags: three.js, webgl, collision-detection

How check collision with terrain mesh in this example http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Heightmap-Textures.html 
All intersection as plane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't check for collision using raycaster as usual because the geometric object is actually a plane, which just appears different because of the shader code.  The best work-around is to write a method that generates geometry object based on image texture, then you can remove shader code, and check for intersections as usual.

Comment: Why not simple use the imagedata? more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687678/issue-with-terrain-collision-using-three-js).